# Find the Gridview control from another Gridview Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
HTMl:-<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="BillOfLadingID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="BillOfLadingID" HeaderText="B/L Number" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="ContainerType" HeaderText="Container Type" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="NumberOfContainer" HeaderText="Number Of Container" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="InvoiceChargesType" HeaderText="Perticulars" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="PerUnit" HeaderText="Per Unit" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="InvoiceINR" HeaderText="INR" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="InvoiceUSD" HeaderText="USD" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                                </Columns>
                                            </asp:GridView>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

C#:- protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            BLID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("GridView2") as GridView;
            gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select BookingWiseContainerTbl.ContainerType,BookingWiseContainerTbl.NumberOfContainer from BookingWiseContainerTbl,LinerBLTbl where LinerBLTbl.BookingID=BookingWiseContainerTbl.LineBookingID and LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID='{0}'", BLID));
            gvOrders.DataBind();

            GridView gvOrders1 = gvOrders.FindControl("GridView3") as GridView;
            gvOrders1.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceChargesType,concat(LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceCurrency,'-', LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceCharges)as PerUnit,LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceINR,LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceUSD  from LinerBLTbl,LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl  where LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID=LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceBillOfLadingID and LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID='" + BLID + "'"));
            gvOrders1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I am using three gridview. In Template Field form another gridview. Now I am trying to bind all gridview data on GridView1 onrowdatabound, I got the gridview2 id on gridview1 on rowdatabound but not gridview3.

How to find the Gridview3 control on gridview1 rowdatabound. I try this but `gvOrders1` is showing null. How to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You will require to use RowDataBound event of GridView2 to bind GridView3 since GridView3 is nested one to it. Here is a sort of similar code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="BillOfLadingID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="BillOfLadingID" HeaderText="B/L Number" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="ContainerType" HeaderText="Container Type" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="NumberOfContainer" HeaderText="Number Of Container" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="InvoiceChargesType" HeaderText="Perticulars" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="PerUnit" HeaderText="Per Unit" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="InvoiceINR" HeaderText="INR" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="300px" DataField="InvoiceUSD" HeaderText="USD" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridClass" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


string BLID = string.Empty;    
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            BLID = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvOrders = e.Row.FindControl("GridView2") as GridView;
            gvOrders.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select BookingWiseContainerTbl.ContainerType,BookingWiseContainerTbl.NumberOfContainer from BookingWiseContainerTbl,LinerBLTbl where LinerBLTbl.BookingID=BookingWiseContainerTbl.LineBookingID and LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID='{0}'", BLID));
            gvOrders.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            GridView gvOrders1 = (sender as GridView).FindControl("GridView3") as GridView;
            gvOrders1.DataSource = GetData(string.Format("select LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceChargesType,concat(LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceCurrency,'-', LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceCharges)as PerUnit,LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceINR,LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceUSD  from LinerBLTbl,LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl  where LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID=LinerInvoiceWiseChargesTbl.InvoiceBillOfLadingID and LinerBLTbl.BillOfLadingID='" + BLID + "'"));
            gvOrders1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```